# How can I make hidden divs always appear at the same spot?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Div structure looks like this:

*c: div with checkbox*

*h: hidden div*

*v: visible div*

**[c1] [h1]**

**[c2] [h2]**

**[c3] [h3]**

**[c4] [h4]**

**[c5] [h5]**

When I click c3 and c4 checkboxes, I want it to look like this:

**[c1]**

**[c2]**

**[c3] [v3]**

**[c4] [v4]**

**[c5]**

But It looks like this:

**[c1] [v3]**

**[c2] [v4]**

**[c3]**

**[c4]**

**[c5]**

I use bootstrap classes like: "row", "col-md-4"

Comment: Share a fiddle (Stack Overflow has something like that built-in) with what you currently have, that way it's easier for people to just edit until they get it right.

Comment: Do you use 'visibility: hidden;' to hide your div's? if not, give it a try, they should still take up space then.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work with bootstrap classes in the checkbox and hidden div, use your own styling and use bootstrap in outer divs.

Here you go:

```js
$("#c1").change(function() {
   $("#h1").toggle();

});

$("#c2").change(function() {
   $("#h2").toggle();

});

$("#c3").change(function() {
   $("#h3").toggle();

});

$("#c4").change(function() {
   $("#h4").toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><input id='c1' type='checkbox'> <span id='h1' style='display:none;'>h1</span></div>
<div><input id='c2' type='checkbox'> <span id='h2'  style='display:none;'>h2</span></div>
<div><input id='c3' type='checkbox'> <span id='h3'  style='display:none;'>h3</span></div>
<div><input id='c4' type='checkbox'> <span id='h4'  style='display:none;'>h4</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First style all the hidden divs with `visibility: hidden`. that will make the divs hidden yet they will retain their places in the page.

Then when the corresponding checkbox will get clicked you will make the div visible by `visibility: visible`.

**Working snippet**

```js
$("#check3").change(function() {
   $('#v3').css('visibility', 'visible');  
    
});
   $("#check4").change(function() {
    $('#v4').css('visibility', 'visible');
    
});
```

```css
.hidden_div {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         
           </head>
<body >
  

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input id="check1" type="checkbox" value="">
    c1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden_div">
    v1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" value="">
    c2

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden_div">
    v2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input id="check3" type="checkbox" value="">
    c3
    </div>
    <div id="v3" class="col-md-4 hidden_div">
    v3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input  id="check4" type="checkbox" value="">
    c4
    </div>
    <div id="v4" class="col-md-4 hidden_div">
    v4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input id="check5" type="checkbox" value="">
    c5
    </div>
    <div  class="col-md-4 hidden_div">
    v5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

**Note** I have used `col-md-4` as mentioned in the question so go full page to see it working.